# React TypeScript: Re render div on mouse move

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to make an image magnifier, when I click the image I am toggling `zoomOn` from true to false when I move the mouse over the image I am saving the x,y position to state, I'm rendering the magnifier and positioning the background image with the x and y. But for some reason, the top, left values are not updating as I move the cursor?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Magnify: React.FC = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    mouseOver: false,
    zoomId: '',
    zoomOn: false,
    zoomPositionX: 0,
    zoomPositionY: 0,
  });

  const {
    zoomId,
    zoomOn,
    mouseOver,
    zoomPositionX,
    zoomPositionY,
  } = state;


  const toggleZoom = () => {
    setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      zoomOn: !zoomOn,
    }));
  };

  const mouseEnter = () => {
    setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      mouseOver: true,
    }));
  };

  const mouseLeave = () => {
    setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      mouseOver: false,
    }));
  };

  const mouseMove = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    event.persist();
    if (zoomOn) {
      setState((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        zoomPositionX: event.nativeEvent.offsetX,
        zoomPositionY: event.nativeEvent.offsetY,
      }));
      renderMagnifier(); // <---- This isnt right!??
    }
  };
  const renderMagnifier = () => {
    return <div className='bus--magnifier' style={magnifierStyle()}></div>;
  };
  const magnifierStyle = () => {
    return {
      backgroundImage: `url('bigtestImage.jpg')`,
      backgroundPosition: `${zoomPositionX}px ${zoomPositionY}px`,
      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
      backgroundSize: '1000px 1000px',
      left: `${zoomPositionY}`,
      top: `${zoomPositionX}`,
    };
  };

  return (
    <div className='magnify'>
      <img
        src='bigtestImage.jpg'
        width={720}
        height={720}
        onClick={toggleZoom}
        onMouseEnter={mouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={mouseLeave}
        onMouseMove={mouseMove}
        className={
          zoomOn && mouseOver
            ? 'magnify--image magnify--over-on'
            : 'magnify--image magnify--over-off'
        }
      />
      {renderMagnifier()}
    </div>
  );
};

export { Magnify };
```

and the scss

```
.magnify {
    max-width: $page-max-width;
    margin: 12px auto;
    position: relative;
    &--image {
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: $depth-1;
        cursor: zoom-in;
    }
    &--over-on {
        cursor: none;
    }
    &--over-off {
        cursor: zoom-in;
    }
    &--magnifier {
        position: absolute;
        border: 2px solid white;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: none;
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        pointer-events: none;  
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

renderMagnifier is just a functional Component so use it as a React.Component and pass zoomPositionX and zoomPositionY to those. A change state change in Magnify will result in a rerender of Magnify and its child Components.

to get changes

```
const Magnifier: React.FC = ({ zoomPositionX, zoomPositionY }) => {

  const magnifierStyle =  {
      backgroundImage: `url('bigtestImage.jpg')`,
      backgroundPosition: `${zoomPositionX}px ${zoomPositionY}px`,
      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
      backgroundSize: '1000px 1000px',
      left: `${zoomPositionY}`,
      top: `${zoomPositionX}`,
  };

  return <div className="bus--magnifier" style={magnifierStyle}></div>;
}

const Magnify: React.FC = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    mouseOver: false,
    zoomId: '',
    zoomOn: false,
    zoomPositionX: 0,
    zoomPositionY: 0,
  });

  const {
    zoomId,
    zoomOn,
    mouseOver,
    zoomPositionX,
    zoomPositionY,
  } = state;


  const toggleZoom = () => {
    setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      zoomOn: !zoomOn,
    }));
  };

  const mouseEnter = () => {
    setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      mouseOver: true,
    }));
  };

  const mouseLeave = () => {
    setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      mouseOver: false,
    }));
  };

  const mouseMove = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    event.persist();
    if (zoomOn) {
      setState((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        zoomPositionX: event.nativeEvent.offsetX,
        zoomPositionY: event.nativeEvent.offsetY,
      }));
      renderMagnifier(); // <---- This isnt right!??
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='magnify'>
      <img
        src='bigtestImage.jpg'
        width={720}
        height={720}
        onClick={toggleZoom}
        onMouseEnter={mouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={mouseLeave}
        onMouseMove={mouseMove}
        className={
          zoomOn && mouseOver
            ? 'magnify--image magnify--over-on'
            : 'magnify--image magnify--over-off'
        }
      />
      <Magnifier zoomPositionX={zoomPositionX} zoomPositionY={zoomPositionY} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `useMemo` from React Hooks to update your magnifier style after state changes.

```
    import { useMemo } from 'react';
    ...
    const magnifierStyle = useMemo(() => {
         return {
          backgroundImage: `url('bigtestImage.jpg')`,
          backgroundPosition: `${state.zoomPositionX}px ${state.zoomPositionY}px`,
          backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
          backgroundSize: '1000px 1000px',
          left: `${state.zoomPositionY}`,
          top: `${state.zoomPositionX}`,
         };
    }, [[state.zoomPositionX, state.zoomPositionY]]);
    ...
    const renderMagnifier = () => {
       return <div className='bus--magnifier' style={magnifierStyle}></div>;
    };
```